# the Value are given to the parameter in the mysql command but it doesn't return the right id

Tags: c#, mysql

Here is an example of the executed query in the program:

```
        Int64 kooid = new Int64();
        myCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT kooiid FROM kooien where NummerExtern =?NummerExtern");
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("?NummerExtern", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = kooi.Kooinr;
        kooid = Convert.ToInt64(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        return kooid;
```

Here is an example of the make up of the table makeup

```
kooiid(int)| kooidlistppg(int)|quarantaine(tiny int) |idvogelsoort(int)|idvogelondersoort(int)| vasteoflossekooie(tiny int)| bezetofniet(tiny int)| idsponsor(int)| NummerExtern(int)
```

Before u ask when i run the query manualy it functions but when ordered by the programm well even if the kooinr variable is correct the query returns a zero to kooiid

Comment: Both function while making command text in c# and the variable is connected to the paramaeter its at kooiid varbiable thats returned that is 0 or null as you would say

Answer (score 0):

found the solution

```
Int64 kooid = new Int64();
        myCommand.CommandText = ("Select kooiid from kooien where NummerExtern = ?NummerExtern");
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("?NummerExtern", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = kooi.Kooinr;
        string kooidstring = myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        kooid = Convert.ToInt64(kooidstring);
        return kooid;
```